# batch file %DATE% use different separators

Tags: batch

I'm trying to run a mysqldump with a date filename

```
mysqldump -umyuser -pmypass mydatabase > c:\backup\%DATE%.sql
```

Problem is, filename is printing as `6/17/12.sql`.  Is there a way to change the separator characters when it tries to write the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system's date format may be set differently than mine (I have "Mon " prefixing my 6/17/13), but you should be able to do a replace on a new variable for date like so

```
set datefix=%DATE%
set datefix=%DATE:/=-%
```

The colon lets it know you're doing a replace, and it sets all "/" to "-" (pick whatever char you want, but remember some have to be escaped).

Output:

```
Mon 06-17-2013.txt
```

Edit: So your batch would be three lines; the two above, then your line looking like this:

```
mysqldump -umyuser -pmypass mydatabase > c:\backup\%datefix%.sql
```